# Django CSRF token missing and API

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-csrf

I am using django 1.11.2 and rest-framework 3.6.3 and the error about csrf token missing is always appearing when sending a react form to API. The annoying thing is that it appears to my only tester/helper (who is quite PC iliterate, that's why he is testing), not to me.

I was able to reproduce the situation in private browsing only, the CSRF cookie is not appearing even when i set ensure_csrf_cookie on the view. Any ideas how to solve this?

This is my settings:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.flatpages',

'rest_framework',
'rest_framework.authtoken',
'rest_auth',
'drf_braces',
'allauth',
'allauth.account',
'allauth.socialaccount',
'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
'allauth.socialaccount.providers.linkedin_oauth2',
'rest_auth.registration', (...)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',

'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.flatpages.middleware.FlatpageFallbackMiddleware',
'project.middleware.TimezoneMiddleware'

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
    'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
),
'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.throttling.AnonRateThrottle',
    'rest_framework.throttling.UserRateThrottle'
),
'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES': {
    'anon': '60/minute',
    'user': '60/minute'
}
```

}

I have tried to use rest-framework's api_view decorator and also the ensure csrf decorator. Nothing helped. The view is class based (from FormView) and the post method, that doesn't work, looks like this:

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator

#@method_decorator(ensure_csrf_cookie)
@api_view(['POST','GET'])
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    (...)
```

The csrf token is retrieved in react code the usual django way. For this purpose I build a csrf react component, that looks like this:

```
function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');

        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = $.trim(cookies[i]);
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(
                  cookie.substring(name.length + 1)
                  );
                break;
            }
        }
    }
return cookieValue;
}


var DjangoCSRFToken = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
    //saving to FormStore, to be send later to the server
    this.props.setValue('csrfmiddlewaretoken',csrftoken);
    return {};
  },

  render: function() {

    var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

    return React.DOM.input(
      {type:"hidden", name:"csrfmiddlewaretoken", value:csrftoken}
      );
  }
});
```

Comment: What do you use as a frontend? Do you pass the csrf token to your POST requests? Is the csrf token in the cookie when you visit your website?

Comment: Well, frontend is a combination of django templates and react form. The csrf token is retrieved in react code the usual way. I will update the question with the component. Totaly forgot about, I am so tired from this, I could fall asleep right now ...

Comment: Do you have access to your testers PC? Maybe some sort of browser plugin / settings prevents cookies. Check if the csrf token is in the cookies for your site.

Comment: try _csrf_exempt()_ decorator above the POST function. Hope it helps!